# mpldatacursor Scatter Plot point colour information

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter, colormap

I have a scatter plot with a colour scaling where each plotted point is associated with another value. This is a lazy workaround to make a "countour plot" style image without having to regularise data points. To make analysis easier I am using mpldatacursor to generate interactive annotations on the plot, and I have a custom formatter which is displaying co-ordinates just fine:

```
datacursor(scatter,
           formatter='$T=${x:.2f}$^\circ$C\n$I=${y:.2f}$\,$mA\n$\Delta F=$$\,$THz'.format,
           draggable=True)
```

but what I really want is for that third line, `$\Delta F=$$\,$THz`, to include a statement that returns the value associated with the colour map at that point. Does anyone know what kwargs I should use to achieve this?

EDIT: MWE

```
from mpldatacursor import datacursor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

scatter = ax.scatter(np.random.random(100),
           np.random.random(100),
           c=np.random.random(100),
           s=0.5)

cb = plt.colorbar(scatter, label="Colour")

datacursor(scatter,
           formatter='$T=${x:.2f}$^\circ$C\n$I=${y:.2f}$\,$mA\n$\Delta F=$$\,$THz'.format,
           draggable=True)
```

Comment: What *is* the "value associated with the colour map at that point"? As usual, you incease chances of getting help here dramatically by providing a clear problem description with a [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest As I say, "I have a scatter plot with a colour scaling where each plotted point is associated with another value."

In other words, I am using 3x1D arrays for this plot. Two for co-ordinates, and one as a colourmap to assign a value to each point. I wish to present the value of the colourmap array within my datacursor formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the index of the picked point to the value to be shown. Therefore the scatter's colors should be publicly available, such that the `ind` of the `pick_event` can index it and return the value at the picked point.

```
from mpldatacursor import datacursor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.random(100)
c = np.random.random(100)

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=1)

cb = plt.colorbar(scatter, label="Colour")

def fmt(**dic):
    tx = '$T=${x:.2f}$^\circ$C\n$I=${y:.2f}$\,$mA\n$\Delta F=${z:.2f}$\,$THz'
    dic.update({"z" : c[dic["ind"][0]]})
    return tx.format(**dic)


datacursor(scatter, formatter=fmt, draggable=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the missing step I needed was to use the "ind" argument to update the dictionary.